# How can I snap my vertex exactly to an edge, if the edge is at an angle?

Tags: edges, snapping

So I am relatively new to blender, and I havent found an answer to this yet.

I have two different objects, and I want to snap my new extruded vertex exactly onto this edge on another object, while also extruding it along the global z axis.

I think you can see it in the picture:[image: snapping exactly to the purple arrow]

I want to snap it exactly to the point where the purple arrow points to.

Comment: Maybe search for "snap to edge" and look through the related questions on the right. there are already a lot of answers on this topic. If none of those helps in your case, please explain wat makes it different and futher clarify what your goal is.